# Creating A-Z index for entries

Tags: ee2, php, list

sorry again for my bad english...

i'd like to create a A-Z list for my entries (recipes) and show them if i click on the related letter.
This code below showing entries by first letter and it's ok but how can i show also empty letters as well?

```
<?php $temp = ''; ?>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="recipes" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
    <?php
    $letter = strtoupper(substr('{title}', 0, 1));
    if ($temp != $letter) {
        echo "<button data-role='letter-loader' class='button-big button-overlay'>" . $letter . "</button>";
        $temp = $letter;
    }
    ?>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

i need something like this, where inactive letters are showing as well:
[image]

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Alphabet is great and you will get excactly wat you want

Answer (score 2):

[Low Alphabet](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet) was created for this exact purpose.

Comment: I can confirm that it works great and is a treat to use. Go check it out!